# How did/do PHP's "higher order" (callback) functions work prior to version 5.3?

Tags: php, function, eval

For example, the array_map function. You pass it a string which is the name of a function. Presumably it doesn't directly eval the string, since you get a specific error:

```
PHP Warning:  array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'dfdgdfg' not found or invalid function name
```

Which is different from the "Call to undefined function" error that you get if you call an undefined function.

So, is it looking up your string in the global symbol table, checking if it exists, and if not, throwing the above exception?

That still doesn't explain how it's calling the function though. Is it doing an eval on the string after checking if it's a defined function?

Comment: I didn't design the language, but why would it have to do an eval? If it's already found the function, it certainly has its location in memory (a pointer, if you will) and so it can call it directly.

Comment: I didn't think of that, because I assumed it was written in PHP which wouldn't let you access memory directly. If someone knows who can chime in...

Comment: That's simply a custom error message text returned there instead of the  `"Call to undefined function"` you assumed. The callback **function name** *string* just has to be valid. It's probed with `function_exists` or alike internally. Inside of PHP/Zend it's using the C call/macro `call_user_function_ex(CG(function_table), ...`

Comment: Thanks! That sastifies my curiosity.